# XML attributes are ignored upon serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, attributes

I am having a weird issue I am banging my head against...

I have a class like this:

```
[XmlRoot("DoesntWork")]
class Root
{
  [XmlElement(ElementName="WontWork", Order=1)]
  public string xmlOutPropertyName
  {...}
}
```

and I am serializing with this:

```
textBox1.Clear();
Root rt = new Root();
rt.xmlOutPropertyName = "[0000000001]";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer();
textBox1.Text = serializer.Serialize(rt);
```

but I always get xml that returns the names of class and property and not the name I want.

```
<Root>
  <xmlOutPropertyName>[0000000001]</xmlOutPropertyName>
</Root>
```

Any idea why this is happening??

Comment: Can you post the _actual_ code you're using? There are several issues with the code you posted (`Root` must be `public`, wrong constructor of `XmlSerializer` used, invalid use of the `Serialize` method). When I copy/paste your code and correct the above issues, it serializes perfectly fine and includes the "DoesntWork" and "WontWork" labels correctly.

Comment: Well I know what I was doing, and I feel like an idiot.

the code is fine, I am just using the RestSharp Serializer....sigh, I was wondering why the examples online were wrong, looks like I need to go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake, I was not paying attention and using the wrong serialization library.